# custom subset of the household objects database

Tags: ros, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use the [household objects database](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database) with a custom objects set?
What I mean is to use the same objects already in the database but instead of loading all of them to be able to specify which subset I want (by giving a list of model ids).
Right now the only options that I know of are "REDUCED_MODEL_SET" and "" which gives me all the objects in the database

Here is an example of a part of a launch file where this is set.

```
  <include file="$(find tabletop_object_detector)/launch/tabletop_node.launch"/>
  <param name="/tabletop_node/use_database" value="true"/>
  <param name="/tabletop_node/model_set" value="REDUCED_MODEL_SET" />
  <param name="/tabletop_node/get_model_list_srv" value="/objects_database_node/get_model_list" />
  <param name="/tabletop_node/get_model_mesh_srv" value="/objects_database_node/get_model_mesh" />

  <node pkg="tabletop_collision_map_processing" name="tabletop_collision_map_processing"
        type="tabletop_collision_map_processing_node" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <param name="tabletop_collision_map_processing/get_model_mesh_srv"
         value="/objects_database_node/get_model_mesh" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10144/custom-subset-of-the-household-objects-database/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's also the DEBUG_MODEL_SET with only a few models.

You're best bet (if you have write access to the database), would be to add your own model set. You just need to add the models number you want to the model_set table, associated with a model set name.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-06-06**:
Ok, no worries. But you do know that setting up a local version of the database won't take you very long and is very straightforward?

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-06-06**:
I guess the right thing would be do get a local version of the database and to modify the entry - however I decided to stick with the full database for now. Thanks

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-06-02**:
Thank you Ugo, but I am using the remote version of the database. I prefer not to have a local version of the database, unless I really really need to.